# Vim "Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc"

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, vim, ubuntu-18.04

After installing vim in ubuntu 18.04 every time I try to use it I get the following Error message:

```
$ vim
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc:
line   57:
E492: Not an editor command:  Source a global configuration file if available
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I didn't change any configuration after installing vim so it's totally pure.

The details of my vim instance:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 10 2018 21:31:58)
Included patches: 1-1453
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
-browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          -toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
-clientserver      +job               -perl              +vertsplit
-clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +virtualedit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +visual
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visualextra
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +viminfo
+comments          +libcall           -python            +vreplace
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +wildignore
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildmenu
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +windows
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +writebackup
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              -X11
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        -xfontset
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -xim
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xpm
-dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xsmp
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xterm_clipboard
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xterm_save
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +syntax            
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-NQEcoP/vim-8.0.1453=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

My OS details:

```
Linux HOSTNAME 4.15.0-42-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

fix on Ubuntu 20.10

Reinstalling with tools:

```
apt purge vim -y && rm -rf /etc/vim && apt install vim* -y
```

The issue: broken config and som of libraries after upgrade Ubuntu20.04 to 20.10 and 18.04 to 20.04;)

fix: Use(*) to install all dependencies plus more usable tools with vim editor

If you don't want it after reinstalling:

```
apt purge vim* -y && apt install vim -y
```

The idea is to install all necessary libraries for "vim" and if don't want
all the tolls you will remove the tools but you will save the necessary libraries
by using your apt package manager, the secret is in (*) ;)

BR

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is due to an uncommented line in `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`

to fix it simply comment line 57 of the file.

so change the content of the line from `Source a global configuration file if available` 
TO `" Source a global configuration file if available`

hopefully if there isn't any other problem it should work without any other complain.

Comment: The line you are referring to is a genuine comment and is always commented out. What you want to comment out is what comes below and sources /etc/vim/vimrc.local if the file is readable. I upvote because it pointed me to the solution.